# Adding multiple nodes at once

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I have created for a mobile site a form to collect daily readings using a content type and that is working like a charm. The question is:

Is there a method, way, module or hack where I can setup some sort of form where the same content type form will be display 7 times (one for each day) and the common fields be merge into one?

The reason for my question is that the regular form make sense to be fill using a mobile device, but if someone wants to use a desktop computer it will make more sense to enter the 7 days of data at once.

Answer (score 2):

[Multi Node Add](http://drupal.org/project/multi_node_add) module could be very helpful for you. With this module you can add multiple nodes at once.

> This module provides a new interface for creating nodes where the users are able to select the fields what they want to use for creating the nodes.
>   It is designed to create multiple nodes in one round, it's possible to add more node input rows on-the-fly.

Answer (score 1):

It won't do exactly what you want, but there is a node copy module that allows a user to copy contents from one node to another, edit it, and submit it as a new one.  It would certainly save time for your users in having to re-type existing data in a form.

http://drupal.org/project/node_clone

Comment: This is definitely an alternative, I will wait a little longer to see if there another method out there. Thank you.